# how to keep the toggle button in preferences for the settings page in android?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I want to create settings page for my android application.In the  settings page is it possible to keep the toggle button in preferences ? if yes ,kindly give me example .thanks in advance

Comment: this site is not a code example dispenser.

Comment: @STTLCU:: i didnt ask for code . i asked whether its possible ??

Comment: if yes, kindly give me example: looks like "gimme code" to me.

Comment: probably but i didnt mean like that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below two method to save and retreive the data in/from shared prefernce

```
public boolean getBooleanFromSP(Context context) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return preferences.getBoolean("togleButtonIsChecked", false);
}//getPWDFromSP()

public void saveBooleanInSP(Context context, boolean value){
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("togleButtonIsChecked", value);
editor.commit();
}//savePWDInSP()
```

Answer (score 1):

it's possible by using shared preferences you can check here [Shared preferences document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

check this tutorial also [Shared Preferences example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)
tutorial 2 [Example of using SharedPreferences](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html)